# Open DBF file in MS access by name

Tags: ms-access, dbf

I am making one form, where you enter a code. Using that code I get the exact Date of that record (e.g Code"100346" goes for record on 14.03.2013, and so on). When I have the record date, I have to open a DBF file (the actual record) with a name formed by the date. 
(e.g Date is 14.03.2013 and the file name will be N140313.DBF)

How can I program access to open/import that exact file, so I can work with it in access?

Comment: it would help if you can show some code. That would make it easy for people to answer.

Comment: Also, which version of Access

Comment: I am using Ms access 2010, because I cant open DBF Files with newer versions. About the code, as I said I'm a complete newbie, when it comes to databases and access in particular. For now I just have a basic form, 1-2 tables and just the algorithm of how to get what I need. The only problem is that I cant't write it

Answer (score 2):

The answer may depend on how (what methods) you want to work with the DBF file, and I don't know what you have in mind there.

Perhaps you would be satisfied with a query to retrieve the DBF data.  I have a dBase III file at this location: *C:\Users\hans\Documents\F_NAMES.DBF*

Then this query in Access 2007 gives me an editable result set ... meaning I can not just view but also alter the stored data.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [dBase III;DATABASE=C:\Users\hans\Documents\].F_NAMES;
```

If you can create a similar query, you could use it as the record source for a form and view and edit your data in that form.

Comment: This code will help me open the DBF file, but the problem is that the DBF file's name depends on what code I've selected. So i need to store the file name in a variable. It should look something like that:



SELECT *
FROM [dBase III;DATABASE=C:\Users\hans\Documents\].SelectedFileName;
,where SelectedFileName is just a string Value that is Automatically made, from a previews selection.

Comment: Build the `SELECT` statement to include the file name the user selected ... the variable's value: `strSelect = "SELECT * FROM [dBase III;DATABASE=C:\Users\hans\Documents\]." & SelectedFileName`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code fragment that I found googling... Its worth a try.  I can't verify it because I have no DBF files...

```
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Dim oneSQL As String


    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\;" & _
            "Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;"

    ' works also
    'strCon = "Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=F:\;"

    cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient   ' allows you to see number of records returned

    cn.Open strCon

    oneSQL = "select * from [data.dbf];"      ' F:\data.dbf

    rs.Open oneSQL, cn, , , adCmdText
```